# What is the term the street thugs called the policemen in Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows?

Tags: historical-accuracy, sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows

When Holmes is following Irene Adler with the package near the start of the movie, he's waylaid by some thugs escorting her and gets into a fight with them.  The fight stops as some policemen (bobbies) go past, one of the thugs shouting out something that sounded like 'Palers' as a warning about the police's presence.

Is that what he shouted?  I recall something about early london police force being named after the lord that started it, or nicknamed as such, was this Lord Pale?  What did he shout, and what's the history on it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word is actually **Peelers**.

Which was slang for Police Officer back then.

From the surname of Sir Robert Peel, who established the Irish constabulary and London's police force.

> Peel entered the Cabinet for the first time as Home Secretary (1822–1827), where he reformed and liberalised the criminal law and created the modern police force, leading to a new type of officer known in tribute to him as "bobbies" and "peelers".

[Wikipedia article on Sir Robert Peel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Peel)